# Waves in Sea depend on Depth of Sea? & Small waves in some sea - Scientific Reason?

Tags: waves

I saw sea without waves in some places. Those places are not having much depth. Do sea waves depend on Sea depth? ?I want to know the scientific reason behind it.

Comment: Where? Mention them explicitly.

Comment: Two places. Rameshwaram and Devipatinam (South India). I didn't see waves in these places.

Comment: Isn't this adequately covered at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_wave)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of this as a complete answer, but it appears that waves over much of the southern tip of India should be somewhat calm because it's fairly well bordered with The Maldive Islands on the SouthWest and Sri Lanka on the East.

[image]

India in general doesn't get very high waves due to smaller bodies of water on it's East and West coasts, not like Australia or California or Hawaii, which are bordered by vast oceans and thousands of miles for wind to transfer energy into waves.   For the southern Tip of India to get big waves from the Indian ocean, the waves would need to travel almost directly north and (I'll be honest, I don't know if that happens or not, maybe it does), but my guess is not, as prevailing winds mostly don't blow direct north.

Here's an [article](http://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/earth/oceanography/question623.htm) on why waves are bigger on the US west coast than the east if interested.

Prevailing wind, depth and slope of the ocean floor all affect wave size, but so does contour of the land.  Devipattinam appears to be in an inlet which might shield it from waves

[image: http://maps.maphill.com/atlas/9n35-79e05/panoramic-maps/shaded-relief-map/rounded-shaded-relief-panoramic-map-of-devipattinam.jpg]

and Rameshwaram is on a string of land that reaches out towards Sri Lanka (close enough that there's even a bridge).   In both cases, there appears to be some degree of natural barriers which can reduce waves.

[image: http://www.holidaytravelreports.com/TouristPlaceStaticMap.aspx?id=147996&url=Devipattinam&loc=Devipattinam,India&lat=9.48&long=78.9]

[image: http://tamildiplomat.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cm-capture-1_1.jpg]

You could try Earth Science stack exchange if you need more specifics on those locations, or was your question more on the physics of wave height to water depth?

Comment: my question is about to know the scientific reason behind "small or no waves in some sea". That's why am asking in this community.

Comment: @LakshmiBalan  I recommend http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

Speed of water waves does sometimes depend on the depth of water given under a certain conditions. When the water gets shallower, more work has to be done in order for the water wave to propagate, resulting in lost of propagational kinetic energy, i believe that is the reason you see no wave at sea with shallower water depth.